# I need to move an object by touching the screen with my finger

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

```
void moveObject()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        TouchPosition = touch.position;

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Ray ray = ARcamera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
            RaycastHit hitObject;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitObject))
            {
                if (hitObject.collider.CompareTag("UnSelected"))
                {
                    hitObject.collider.gameObject.tag = "Selected";
                }
            }
        }

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            ARRaycastManagerScript.Raycast(TouchPosition, hits);
            SelectedObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("Selected");
            SelectedObject.transform.position = hits[0].pose.position;
        }

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            if (SelectedObject.CompareTag("Selected"))
            {
                SelectedObject.tag = "UnSelected";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

We are talking about an augmented reality assistant that flies in the air in front of a teleophone screen, I need to make it so that it can be moved with the touch of a finger across the screen. It seems that I set everything up in Unity as it should, but it still does not work .. maybe there is some problem in the code? (

Comment: what exactly does `still does not work` mean? Why use these tags? Just store the object you move in a field?

Comment: under the words does not work, I meant that there are no errors in Unity, but at the same time I can not move the object with my finger ...
that is, I need to declare a bool variable, set it to false, assign it to the object that needs to be moved, and if the ray crosses this object, then we set this variable to true, and if this variable is true, then we execute the code that is responsible for the object to move there, where does the finger lead?

Comment: well did you try to debug your raycast etc? Maybe you are hitting something else which doesn't have the tag `Unselected`

Comment: yeah, that is, it is necessary that all the components from which the object that we want to move has tag with name Unselected?